# Issue setting Java Compliance level to newest JDK (16)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, spring-tools-4

I successfully installed and verified JDK 16 yesterday, but was unable to set Compiler Compliance Level to 16 (from Preferences/Java/Compiler). 15 is as high as it goes. I did install new updates today, but still unable to select 16 compliance level. I am using last Intel CPU MacBook Pro with current Big Sur OS, and STS 4: Spring Tool Suite 4 Version: 4.9.0.RELEASE, Build Id: 202012132054

I did make the new JDK available from preferences, and tested that new JDK works from command line in Terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: Java 16 was released 2 days ago. Give it some time and you'll get the update.

Comment: Eclipse 2021-03 with a patch is the first to support Java 16.

Comment: You can try IntelliJ https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/01/intellij-idea-2021-1-eap-1/

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Tools for Eclipse 4.9.0 release is based on Eclipse 2020-12, which didn't come with support for JDK16. Therefore you don't see an option to use this JDK in your preferences and you don't see an option to switch the internal compiler level to Java 16.

The latest Spring Tools 4.10.0 release is based on Eclipse 2021-03, which also doesn't ship support for JDK16 out-of-the-box. But you can install the JDK16 support from the Eclipse marketplace once you have Spring Tools for Eclipse 4.10.0 installed.

This video about the latest Eclipse 2021-03 release shows you how to install the JDK16 support: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGGALLHnH-c